# SustainsSys SAML form data duplicate key issue

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I am trying to submit the form data on SustainSys Stub IDP page as part of automation test suite that is simulating SAML login without involving the browser.

I am submitting the form data POST request but it appears that the duplicate keys required by the form are not being submitted in the form data.
Request looks like this:

```
request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/{id}',
      form: true,
      body: {
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index": "0",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[0].Type": "urn:oid:2.5.4.10",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[0].Value": "Test 123",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index": "1",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[1].Type": "https://some-url.com",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[1].Value": "001",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index": "2",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[2].Type": "https://some-url.com",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[2].Value": "Open",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index": "16",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[16].Type": "urn:oid:2.5.4.4",
          "AssertionModel.AttributeStatements[16].Value": 'Admin-Smith'
  }
    })
```

The issue is with the `"AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index"` properties as only the last one with value `16` is being sent by the JS Library I am using for the request. As a result the SAML response being returned isn't correct. How can these properties be sent so they are parsed correctly by the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `"AssertionModel.AttributeStatements.Index"` properties are not actually required. the request works without these.